# list.files and file extension selection - R

Tags: r

I have a folder that contain many file formats, how can I only select txt file extensions?

```
lf <- list.files("E:/UUU/", full.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use the `pattern` argument to match all files with a `.` (as `.` is a metacharacter, we escape (`\\`) it) followed by the string 'txt' and specify that it is at the end (`$`) of the string

```
lf <- list.files(path = "E:/UUU/", pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names=TRUE)
```

---

By default, the `pattern` is set as NULL, so it will select all the files in the folder.  If we check the `Usage` from `?list.files`

> list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
>              full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
>              ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)